# Remove spaces from a string C# (something simple!)

Tags: c#, string, spaces

Hi guys I can't find out why my code is not working, any help would be really appreciated!

I have a given string filled with numbers and space between each number I have to remove the spaces so that I get all the numbers glued to each other..

```
    string nums = "1 2 3 4 5";
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i].ToString() == " ")
        {
            nums[i].ToString() = "";
        }
    }
```

I also tried using .Replace(" ", ""); but again no success, I can't figure out where I'm doing it wrong.. I need a simple, beginner friendly solution!

Comment: Strings are immutable

Comment: I don't understand why `var newString = nums.Replace(" ", "")` doesn't work? What was the issue with that?

Comment: .Replace should have worked.  Try single quotes instead of double.

Comment: And in general, *any* statement of the form `foo.MethodCall() = something;` will fail to compile. The target of an assignment has to be a variable or a property - *not* the result of a method call.

Comment: @Satpal http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am surprised and disappointed this question has a downvote. It's very beginner, but OP did everything we ask: describe the desired outcome, show what's been tried so far, and an explain outright s/he can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @DanAndrews That's not only not going to fix the problem, but it's not going to compile because empty character literals are invalid. It's quite clear that his problem is not assigning the result of the `Replace` call back to the original string variable.

Comment: @AntP WHAT?  Look at the MS example, this would work: `nums = nums.Replace(' ', String.Empty);`

Comment: @DanAndrews He isn't trying to replace it with a comma, though, is he? Again, **empty string literals are invalid**, so replacing his double quotes with single ones would cause his code not to compile.

Comment: come on, I copied and pasted it.

Comment: @DanAndrews That *still* isn't going to compile. There is no `Replace(char,string)` overload. What you're looking for is a null character - `'\0'`.

Comment: ... I really wasn't trying to answer in a comment.  I suggested trying single quote in a comment - which at that time he / we / I would have noticed the missing overload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in .NET are immutable. Calling `nums[i].ToString()` gives you a new string, without modifying `nums`.

`Replace` is the way to go, but you have to assign result back to `nums`:

```
string nums = "1 2 3 4 5";

nums = nums.Replace(" ", "");
```

It's necessary, because `Replace` does not modify source string. It returns new one instead.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! The problem with my replace obviously was again that I wasnt assigning it back to nums! Stupid me xD I've been doing homeworks all day and my brain is fried, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This method will remove the spaces out of your string. What it does is iterates through each char and then compares it to the  UTF-16 value for space. If it's a space it won't add it.

```
public String RemoveSpaces(String withSpaces){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < withSpaces.Length; i++)
    {
        if (withSpaces[i] != 32)
        {
           sb.Append(withSpaces[i]);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Well, your code certainly does what it is doing correctly, and certainly in a much more creative way than just using the boring `string.Replace(" ", string.Empty)` ;)

Comment: Haha Okay, so yes, I admit there ARE easier ways. But who wants a plain jane string.replace?

Comment: I call that challenging the status quo :-D I have to admit, i am always in for a challenge, too :)

Comment: You know, some times you have to look at the standard and say "I know you're more efficiently written. I know you are less code for me to write and I know that my peers will look down on me if I don't use you. But I'm in college damn it and my professor wants me to do things the hard way!"

Comment: Very well said, very well said :-D

Comment: This works because 32 is the UTF-16 code-unit for the Unicode space character. Thanks to the Unicode designers, it's the same as ASCII. (`withSpaces[i]` is a `char`, which is a UTF-16 code-unit.)

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes, you're correct. Thank you for that clarification. I forgot that it was in fact a different set that just matched it.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning to the output of a function call (`ToString()`) which is wrong. Use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to replace characters in a string.